# Can my chef-server and workstation be on different clouds ..?

Tags: knife, chef-infra

Say .. I have a scenario where my workstation is in my local network and my chef server is in AWS . In knife.rb ,i gave the AWS Public IP in the chef server url. Will this work or not for open source chef .??

i tried doing that.i am getting the following error:-

```
ERROR: Network Error: Error connecting to https://xx.xx.xx.xx/cookbooks?num_versions=all - Connection timed out - connect(2)
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

can some one help me out in this.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, as long as your workstation (usually your PC/Mac) has IP connectivity to the Chef server that's how it works. Given your output, it looks like access to port 443 is not allowed (or you entered the wrong IP of your chef server).